# Connect to previously connected Wifi in Android Q programmatically

Tags: android, android-10.0

I'm looking for a way to connected to wifi without passing the password, With the deprecation of **wifiManager.enableNetwork** API I haven't found a way to switch over from wifi to wifi. I have a list of scanned wifi and want to connect to a network, SSID already known. Pls help.

// Method to restore a known network

```
private String restoreDefaultConnection(final String defaultSSID) {
    List<ScanResult> scanResults = wifiManager.getScanResults();
    for (ScanResult item : scanResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SSID::" + item.SSID + " BSSID:" + item.BSSID);
        if (defaultSSID.equals("\"" + item.SSID + "\"")) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Found default wifi");
            connectToNetwork(item.SSID, null);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "No wifi SSID found for default network");
        }
    }
}
```

// Method to connect to network

```
public void connectToNetwork(final String networkSSID, final String networkPass) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Connecting to Wi-Fi network: " + networkSSID);
    WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder builder = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder();
    builder.setSsid(networkSSID);
    if (networkPass != null) builder.setWpa2Passphrase(networkPass);

    WifiNetworkSpecifier wifiNetworkSpecifier = builder.build();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        NetworkRequest.Builder networkRequestBuilder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
        networkRequestBuilder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            networkRequestBuilder.setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier);
        }
        NetworkRequest networkRequest = networkRequestBuilder.build();
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {
                super.onAvailable(network);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) cm.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
            }

            @Override
            public void onUnavailable() {
                Log.d(TAG, "App could not connect to wifi");
                super.onUnavailable();
            }
        };
        cm.requestNetwork(networkRequest, networkCallback);
    }
}
```

Comment: `cm.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback)` Please note that this method just disconnect the wifi connected programlly, and the phone will connect to WiFi according to its own policy

Comment: @Delink Do you find any solution?

Comment: @ahmednawazCS No I have never found a solution to this, any leads?

Comment: @Delink nope, I did a lot RnD but cannot find any solution. I have the same requirement as, switching wifi network and the second case is to get system hotspot credentials programmatically or create a hotspot that can share internet.